# Remove the node of xml depending on another node id using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need an help regarding the XSL ,please find my xml below

```
<TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
  <TEST>
    <TEST1>
      <TEST2>
        <A>
          <Rule>e1fa7f63820a406bb97f1c1b11af8d09</Rule>
          <MountPoint>0</MountPoint>
        </A>
        <A>
          <Rule>917271928cea4a75bdfa903b49ed23e5</Rule>
          <MountPoint>0</MountPoint>
        </A>
        <A>
          <Rule>6b6336722d574e8285b73192ea057b45</Rule>
          <MountPoint>0</MountPoint>
        </A>
      </TEST2>
    </TEST1>
    <CHECK>
      <CHECK1>
        <Rule>
          <Name>test1</Name>
          <ID>6b6336722d574e8285b73192ea057b45</ID>
          <Type>DicomHeaderAttribute</Type>
          <Category>SeriesDate</Category>
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Value>as</Value>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>sdsd</Name>
          <ID>e1fa7f63820a406bb97f1c1b11af8d09</ID>
          <Type>DicomHeaderAttribute</Type>
          <Category>SeriesInformation</Category>
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Value>sdsdsd</Value>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>fdfdf</Name>
          <ID>917271928cea4a75bdfa903b49ed23e5</ID>
          <Type>DicomHeaderAttribute</Type>
          <Category>ReferringPhysician</Category>
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Value>assd</Value>
        </Rule>
      </CHECK1>
    </CHECK>
  </TEST>
</TEST>
```

In the above xml i need to remove the rules matching with  Category value as `'SeriesInformation'`, and also the corresponding 'A' node which matches with the ID of the `'SeriesInformation'` Rule,

The expected XML:

```
<TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
  <TEST>
    <TEST1>
      <TEST2>
        <A>
          <Rule>917271928cea4a75bdfa903b49ed23e5</Rule>
          <MountPoint>0</MountPoint>
        </A>
        <A>
          <Rule>6b6336722d574e8285b73192ea057b45</Rule>
          <MountPoint>0</MountPoint>
        </A>
      </TEST2>
    </TEST1>
    <CHECK>
      <CHECK1>
        <Rule>
          <Name>test1</Name>
          <ID>6b6336722d574e8285b73192ea057b45</ID>
          <Type>DicomHeaderAttribute</Type>
          <Category>SeriesDate</Category>
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Value>as</Value>
        </Rule>
        <Rule>
          <Name>fdfdf</Name>
          <ID>917271928cea4a75bdfa903b49ed23e5</ID>
          <Type>DicomHeaderAttribute</Type>
          <Category>ReferringPhysician</Category>
          <Operator>Equals</Operator>
          <Value>assd</Value>
        </Rule>
      </CHECK1>
    </CHECK>
  </TEST>
</TEST>
```

Please help in XSL.

Hi ,this is xsl iam using

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Rule[Category = 'SeriesInformation']">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

iam not able to forward after that,, iam able to delete the rule that matches with category as SeriesInformation, but after that how to delete
 the A nodes depending on ID iam not able to do

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `A` elements, you could define a key to look up the `Rule` elements by `ID`

```
<xsl:key name="rule" match="Rule[ID]" use="ID" />
```

Then, the template match to ignore the `A` elements is as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="A[key('rule', Rule)/Category='SeriesInformation']" />
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="rule" match="Rule[ID]" use="ID" />

    <xsl:template match="Rule[Category='SeriesInformation']" />

    <xsl:template match="A[key('rule', Rule)/Category='SeriesInformation']" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```